# Junit test that will fail if singleton getInstance() method is not synchronized

Tags: java, multithreading, junit, synchronization, thread-safety

I have this singelton Database that I've build, and this Junit test I've created:

singleton

```
package SingeltonDBVersion1;

import GlobalSetting.User;

/****************************************************************************
 * This is the SingeltonDB. it warps the object DBconn according to the
 * Singleton pattern. it receive name and password (i.e. DBConn parameters) and
 * if it is the first time that a UserContorll try to get an instance it connect
 * to the database. After that, the DBConn instance will be return to the user.
 *****************************************************************************/
public class SingeltonDB {
    private static DBconnImpl db = null;
    private static SingeltonDB singalDb = null;
    boolean first = true;

    private SingeltonDB(String username, String password) {
        if (first) {
            try {
                System.out.println("first");
                Thread.sleep(5000);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            first = false;
        }
        db = new DBconnImpl();
    }

    public static SingeltonDB getInstance(String username, String password)
            throws Exception {
        if (db != null) {
            return singalDb;
        }

        singalDb = new SingeltonDB(username, password);
        System.out.println("The database is now open");
        db.connect(username, password);
        System.out.println("The database was connected");
        return singalDb;
    }

    public void create(String tableName) throws Exception {
        db.create(tableName);
    }

    public User query(String tableName, int userID) throws Exception {
        if (db == null) {
            System.out.println("Error: the database is not open");
            return null;
        }
        return (db.query(tableName, userID));
    }

    public void update(String tableName, User user) throws Exception {
        if (db == null) {
            System.out.println("Error: the database is not open");
            return;
        }
        db.update(tableName, user);
    }

    public void disconnect() throws Exception {
        db.disconnect();
    }

    public static void reset() throws Exception {
        db = null;
    }
}
```

Junit

```
package Tests;

import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

import org.junit.Test;

import SingeltonDBVersion1.SingeltonDB;


public class SingeltonDBVersion1Tests {

        @Test
        public synchronized void testSynch() throws Exception {
            int num=2;
            CountDownLatch doneSignal = new CountDownLatch(num);

            MySingeltonDB[] instances = new MySingeltonDB[num];
            for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
                instances[i]=new MySingeltonDB(doneSignal);

            }
            SingeltonDB.reset();
            for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
                instances[i].run();

            }
             doneSignal.await(); 
                for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) { 
                    for (int j = i; j < instances.length; j++) {
                        if (instances[i].getDB()!=instances[j].getDB())
                        {
                            throw (new Exception());
                        }
                    }
                }
        }


    class MySingeltonDB implements Runnable {
        SingeltonDB db;
        CountDownLatch doneSignal;

        public MySingeltonDB(CountDownLatch doneSignal) {
            this.db = null;
            this.doneSignal = doneSignal;
        }

        public SingeltonDB getDB() {
            return db;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                this.db = SingeltonDB.getInstance("MyAccount", "123");
                doneSignal.countDown();
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------->"+db );
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do here is to create 2 instance of the singleton if and only if the singletonDB method: getInstance() is not synchronized. but for some reason the singleton is working properly and return one instance of the class even if I don't use the synchronized in the method.

Comment: You seem to be creating instances sequentially, so it is likely your pseudo-singleton will actually work as a singleton in this context.

Comment: I'd try using an `Executor` and create a greater number of instances - 2 is too limited. Although in the end, using a unit test to check if a singleton is an actual singleton would be pointless (i.e. you could spare yourself the unit test) if you employed a true singleton idiom.

Comment: I am creating the instances sequentially, but the call to getInstnace of each one of them is being done in the thread run() method, so doesn't it qualified as parallel?

Comment: I know, but it is a question I was asked during a job intreview to see if I know threads well enough...

Comment: Is the requirement "write a JUnit test that will fail if the getInstance() method of a given singleton class is not synchronized"?

Comment: You won't be able to write a test that will definitely fail if your method isn't `synchronized`. You could write a test that *may* fail on some occasions, if the threads are scheduled in a convenient way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try my test, it reproduces the problem:

```
static class Singleton {
    static Singleton i;

    static Singleton getInstance() {
        if (i == null) {
            i = new Singleton();
        }
        return i;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Callable<Singleton> c = new Callable<Singleton>() {
        @Override
        public Singleton call() throws Exception {
            return Singleton.getInstance();
        }
    };
    ExecutorService ex = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    for(;;) {
        Future<Singleton> f1 = ex.submit(c);
        Future<Singleton> f2 = ex.submit(c);
        if (f1.get() != f2.get()) {
            System.out.println("!!!");
        }
        Singleton.i = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your test is not complete. Because you wait for all thread to finish, but you are not waiting for all thread to be ready. Add one more new `new CountDownLatch(1)`, before starting a thread, like in [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) example. That will guarantee, that all thread are starting simultaneously.

```
import org.junit.Test;

import SingeltonDBVersion1.SingeltonDB;


public class SingeltonDBVersion1Tests {

        @Test
        public synchronized void testSynch() throws Exception {
            int num=2;
            CountDownLatch startSignal = new CountDownLatch(1);
            CountDownLatch doneSignal = new CountDownLatch(num);

            SingeltonDB.reset();    
            Thread[] instances = new Thread[num];
            for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
                instances[i]=new Thread(new MySingeltonDB(startSignal, doneSignal)).start();

            }
             startSignal.countDown(); 
             doneSignal.await(); 
                for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) { 
                    for (int j = i; j < instances.length; j++) {
                        if (instances[i].getDB()!=instances[j].getDB())
                        {
                            throw (new Exception());
                        }
                    }
                }
        }


    class MySingeltonDB implements Runnable {
        SingeltonDB db;
        CountDownLatch startSignal;
        CountDownLatch doneSignal;

        public MySingeltonDB(CountDownLatch startSignal, CountDownLatch doneSignal) {
            this.db = null;
            this.startSignal = startSignal;
            this.doneSignal = doneSignal;
        }

        public SingeltonDB getDB() {
            return db;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                startSignal.await();
                this.db = SingeltonDB.getInstance("MyAccount", "123");
                doneSignal.countDown();
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------->"+db );
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

And start using threads at all. ;) The code from your sample is running in a single thread. I'd be surprised if it ever fails.